# AVAudioPlayer not playing the second time consistently

Tags: avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer object configured and play it at an appropriate time. However, if I try to play the same object the second time it sometimes plays and sometimes does not (quite unpredictable).

```
-(void)loadBeepSound{
  ....    
  self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:beepURL error:&error];
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
  else{
      [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
  }}
```

The above loadBeepSound method is called once and then later on whenever I need to play it, I am just using the play method.

```
        if (self.audioPlayer) {
        [self.audioPlayer play];
    }
```

Is there something additional that should be done, such as always play it from the main thread, etc.? self.audioPlayer is never becoming null, I have checked that.

Comment: You could try implementing the AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods:
`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` and 
`audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error:` and see if they can tell you more about whether the playback is failing.

Comment: When the sound is not played, none of the two delegate methods is getting called. Might be a threading related issue.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Im having problem even if i execute the code on main thread.